# here-api maptileservice is deprecated and will be removed soon

Tags: here-api, deprecated

we have some references to here map tile v2.1 and the H.service.Platform.createDefaultLayers function is telling us the MapTileService and traffic.Service classes are deprecated and will be removed soon.
the raster tile api v3 is now available, but i cannot find a date when the old map tile v2 will become unavailable as a deadline to complete the migration.
does anyone know?

have searched heremaps developer website

Answer (score 0):

just found out that the services will be discontinued on 2023-12-31.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).